# "So also in matters psychological" Is that English at all?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a book, Gestalt Therapy Integrated, and I stumble on this sentence:

> So also in matters psychological.

I'm thinking that one line is missing, but I'd like to make sure of  that.

The paragraph starts in this way:

> Were an individual subjected to great heat, he would soon lose contact by fainting and he might eventually die if his limits for assimilating heat were seriously trespassed. So also in matters psychological.

Comment: I'd need the reference in context - lose contact with what? Trespasses looks like it should be trespassed. Is this a text that's been scanned and digitised?

Comment: Apart from the typo Leon mentioned, that quote makes sense to me. It's saying that in psychological matters, exposure to excessive ‘heat’ (which I presume the following lines will define what is in a psychological context) will make you lose contact, etc., just like exposure to excessive physical heat will in a physiological context.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, the author uses physical heat as an example here to what is being discussed: contact. To much contact (with someone, something, self thoughts...) and you could psychologically _trespass_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct.

The sentence indicates that the individual would be compromised psychologically.

This sentence structure is seen in writings from the Victorian era but is less commonly seen in modern usage.

Comment: I don't see what is archaic about it. It is very good English. If you rarely see it your reading must be limited. My wife, who is versed in matters psychological, informs me that Gestalt has been written in the last thirty years.

Comment: Ah... My edition is 1973. So not Victorian, really, but the meaning you transpose is what I was thinking it would be.

Comment: Just to confirms, no verbs in the sentence, right? _matters_ is the noon?

Comment: @Chenmunka I would tend to agree with your answer as edited. Though I am one who welcomes older and more mature idioms.

Comment: @Alexis, yes, _matters_ is a noun here.

Comment: @Alexis Wilke. Yes, in this context _matters_ is a noun, followed by a postpositive adjective. Garner in _Modern American Usage_ (p648) has an entry on such adjectives which "_follow the nouns they modify, generally because they follow Romance rather than Germanic (English) syntax. They exist in English largely as a remnant of the Norman French influence during the Middle Ages._" Among Garner's examples are: _attorney general, heir apparent, notary public_.

Comment: Garner goes on to state: "_At least two common English nouns, 'matters' and 'things', often take postpositive adjectives that are ordinarily prepositive. Thus we say that someone is interested in 'matters philological' or 'things philosophical'._"

Comment: Yes. Think of it as having no "that/which are/is" before the (postpositive) adjective.

Comment: @Shoe, thank you for explaining the origin. "En matière psychologique" makes sense to me. So it is a direct translation from French!